# Calculating residues of multiple poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have $f(z)=\dfrac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2}$, and I need its residue at $z=i$, which is a double pole. I tried expanding $f(w+i)$, where I got to $f(w+i)=w^{-2}\dfrac{(w^2+2iw-1)e^{iw-1}}{(w+2i)^2}$ and going further was a pain, and each time somehow gave me 0 as the residue, which isn't right. I don't really know of any other ways of finding residues at a multiple pole!

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles)

Comment: @FireGarden Are you looking for a general approach or are you looking for a way to solve this specific problem?

Comment: @GitGud I was looking for a solution to this specific problem. This is simply part of an exam question that was only 10 marks, so I thought I'd wait for potentially simpler approaches (which I had assumed existed that I missed).

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate first the first derivative of $\;(z-i)^2f(z)\;$:

$$(z-i)^2f(z)=\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2}\implies \frac d{dz}\left((z-i)^2f(z)\right)=\frac{(2z+iz^2)e^{iz}(z+i)-2z^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^3}\implies$$

$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac d{dz}\left((z-i)^2f(z)\right)=\frac{-2e^{-1}+2e^{-1}}{2i}=0$$